# Google Visualization API inside YUI3 Sandbox

Tags: charts, google-visualization, yui3

I am using YUI3 as the javascript framework for my application which is about 90% complete. I need to show some pretty charts, but YUI3's charting capabilities leaves a lot to be desired.

I am trying to use Google's Visualization API to generate plots within YUI3 sandbox but it seems to not be working. Here is the sample code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src = 'build/yui/yui-min.js'></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>

<script type='text/javascript'>

var some_foo = function () {      
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
}


YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
    /* doing some super-awesome stuff */

    /* now trying to show charts with some data */  
    some_foo();
});

</script>
```

When I place the call to some_foo() outside the YUI3 sandbox, the code works. However, when I try to call it from within YUI3, it does not work.

I have also tried declaring some_foo() within YUI3 sandbox, outside YUI3 sandbox, before YUI3 sandbox, and also after YUI3 sandbox. I have tried the code on FF14+ and Chrome20+.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

@KingJulian, not sure if you already have the answer by now. I moved the  `google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});` from the "some_foo" function to a "script" tag and it worked.

Following code worked for me:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
   <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.6.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

var some_foo = function () {      

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
}


YUI().use('node', function (Y) {

   some_foo();
});

</script>
```